# Oracle apex: Hide a selectlist with dynamic actions not working

Tags: oracle, dynamic, action, show-hide

I'm having two select lists:
P8_BUSINESSRULETYPE - which has a query to select all the businessruletypes
P8_OPERATOR - which has a query to select the operator based on the value of P8_BUSINESSRULETYPE

I'm having a dynamic action which has to hide the operator selectlist when P8_BUSINESSRULETYPE = 9 OR P8_BUSINESSRULETYPE = 10 OR P8_BUSINESSRULETYPE = 7

My dynamic action:
Event: change
Selectiontype :item(s)
Item(s): P8_BUSINESSRULETYPE
condition: is not null

true actions: hide items p8_OPERATOR
false actions: show items p8_operator

condition: PL/SQL Expression
:P8_BUSINESSRULETYPE = '10' OR :P8_BUSINESSRULETYPE = '7'  OR :P8_BUSINESSRULETYPE = '9'

I hope someone will be able to tell me what's wrong with my dynamic action and why it's still always showing P8_OPERATOR.

Thank you very much,

Elvira

Comment: I'm confused - first you say the condition is "is not null", then you say it is "PL/SQL Expression". Which is it?

Comment: By the way, your condition would be simpler written as `:P8_BUSINESSRULETYPE IN ('10','7','9')`.